# How do I click a command by codes on right side menu?

Tags: codenameone

I have a command added to the right-side menu of a form.
I want to click the command by code but the `pointerPressed()` is for components and `pressed()` is for buttons.

A Command is not a component. How do I click a command by codes?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a button, we just make it for you. Use:

```
Button btn = toolbar.findCommandComponent(cmd);
```

You can then use events and customize the appearance of the `Button` as you would with any `Button`.

Comment: back command for back to the previous form. The showback() doesn't be called when click backBtn. getToolbar().setBackCommand(previous.back,BackCommandPolicy.AS_REGULAR_COMMAND); setBackCommand(previous.back); back = new Command("",icon) { @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { if (resetContent()){ showBack(); } } }; backBtn = getToolbar().findCommandComponent(back);

Comment: Back command is a bit of a special case as it might not contain a component and might be fired from a hardware button. Try `form.dispatchCommand()` for that case.

Comment: Would you provide the sample code about `dispatchCommand()`? Thank you.

Comment: You just pass the command and create an action event. Literally `parentForm.dispatchCommand(myCommand, new ActionEvent(parentForm));`